# AngularJS circular dependency with interdependent associations

Tags: angularjs, coffeescript, associations, circular-dependency

In my angularJS app, I use factories for each of my models. These models have associations with each other. For example if I have a `User` model and a `Post` model, a user might have many posts, and a post might have many tagged users. I have an service that automates loading these associations.

However, I have a circular dependency problem here. My `User` model depends on my `Post` model, and vice versa. I could earlier bypass this by using `$injector` in the association service to dynamically load the models. With recent angularJS versions, it seems this no longer works.

I've read [Misko's post](http://misko.hevery.com/2008/08/01/circular-dependency-in-constructors-and-dependency-injection/) about circular dependencies - but I'm not sure what to do in this situation - it seems like I need this circular dependency. Can someone suggest a better way to go about this, or some way to bypass the circular dependency issue?

EDIT: Putting in some example code to make things clearer:

```
angular.module('some-module')
    .factory('Post', ['BaseModel', 'HasManyAssociation', 'User',
        (BaseModel, HasManyAssociation, User) ->
            class Post extends BaseModel
                # ... logic and fields particular to this model...

                _associations: [new HasManyAssociation('tagged_users', 'tagged_user_ids', User)]
    ])

    .factory('User', ['BaseModel', 'HasManyAssociation', 'Post',
        (BaseModel, HasManyAssociation, Post) ->
            class User extends BaseModel
                # ... logic and fields particular to this model...

                _associations: [new HasManyAssociation('posts', 'post_ids', Post)]
    ])
```

I'm using coffeescript classes pretty extensively here. The BaseModel class has all the logic I need for a general model. The HasManyAssociation converts association data into an array of models when it is loaded from the server.

I'm not sure if that really makes things much clearer, though I hope it does..

Comment: I believe the solution is to extract what about them depends on one another into a service or even a whole module - whatever the circumstance calls for - and make them both depend on that.

Comment: If you show your code, I could help you refactor it.

Comment: I've added in a bit of code - does that help?

Comment: Ah, there `$injector` was being used in `HasManyAssociation` to instantiate associated factories. Updated the code so the dependency is passed directly - that should make it clearer.

Comment: Yes, I'm pretty sure you could easily pass them both another service that they will add their data to so that it is available to them both. It sounds like the same principle of sharing data between controllers with a service, but here you want to share data between services. Another service will take care of it in either case.

Comment: I'm not sure how - these factories are not instances of `User` and `Post`. Instances are constructed from the `User` and `Post` class - and each `User` instance needs to construct child `Post` instances, and vice versa.